# How to coarse grain xy coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an xy array of gps coordinates that are not evenly sampled. That seems obvious but I would like to project it onto a grid. Here is my script for the context:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata

gps_track = np.array([[0,0],[1.2,2.3],[1.9,3],[3.2,4.3],[4,2.9],[6.5,3.1]])
x = gps_track[:,0]
y = gps_track[:,1]

# define grid
binsize = 1
xmin, xmax = x.min(), x.max()
ymin, ymax = y.min(), y.max()
xi = np.arange(xmin, xmax+binsize, binsize)
yi = np.arange(ymin, ymax+binsize, binsize)
```

How do I proceed from here to get the (xnew, ynew) values interpolated on the (xi, yi) grid given the (x, y) original coordinates?

```
# grid the data
xnew, ynew = grid(x, y, xi, yi)
```

I thought I would use something similar to the matplotlib function griddata:

```
zi = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi)
```

Which I can't do; I want to grid the coordinates themselves, not the value z = f(x,y). Do you know of any fast solution that would do it?

EDIT:
It really helps. You guys rock! To be more accurate in my request, I have taken the plot you've generated and marked the (xnew, ynew) samples I am expecting to get with hollow circles. They fall on the (xi, yi) grid.

[image]

Comment: I cannot understand what you exactly ask. You need to do interpolation and plot a continuous line using the interpolated data, right?

Comment: I would interpolate between two consecutive (x, y) points (could be linear, cubic...) and return only the values that happen to be on the (xi, yi) grid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate as interpolate

gps_track = np.array([[0,0],[1.2,2.3],[1.9,3],[3.2,4.3],[4,2.9],[6.5,3.1]])
x = gps_track[:,0]
y = gps_track[:,1]

binsize = 1.0
xmin, xmax = x.min(), x.max()
ymin, ymax = y.min(), y.max()
xi = np.arange(xmin, xmax+binsize, binsize)
yi = np.arange(ymin, ymax+binsize, binsize)

N = 1000
tckp, u = interpolate.splprep([x, y], s=0, k=2, nest=-1)
xx, yy = interpolate.splev(np.linspace(0, 1, N), tckp)

# find integer indices where the xx fall between xi values
x_idx = np.searchsorted(xi, xx)
# find where the x_idx indices change. This is where the curve crosses a grid line 
x_mask = np.diff(x_idx) != 0
# do the same for y
y_idx = np.searchsorted(yi, yy)
y_mask = np.diff(y_idx) != 0

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(xx, yy)
ax.scatter(xx[x_mask], yy[x_mask], color='red')
ax.scatter(xx[y_mask], yy[y_mask], color='red')

# make sure the grid lines fall on xi and yi
ax.set_xticks(xi)
ax.set_yticks(yi)
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

yields
[image]

---

`xi`, `yi` define your grid.

`xx`, `yy` are points on the interpolated path.

To find points on the vertical grid lines, first use `np.searchsorted` to find
the *index* (of `xi`) where
each value in `xx` (the x-data) would fit into the sorted array `xi` (the grid).

```
In [88]: x_idx = np.searchsorted(xi, xx)
In [89]: x_idx
Out[89]: 
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
       4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
       6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7])
```

We can then take the difference of neighboring values:

```
In [91]: np.diff(x_idx)
Out[91]: 
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

Where the value is non-zero indicates that the path has crossed a grid line.

```
In [93]: x_mask = (np.diff(x_idx) != 0)

In [94]: x_mask
Out[94]: 
array([ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

The `x_mask` can then be used to find the x-values of points on the interpolated
path closest to a grid line:

```
In [95]: xx[x_mask]
Out[95]: 
array([ -6.93660834e-18,   9.65180188e-01,   1.95810449e+00,
         2.94969940e+00,   3.94167195e+00,   4.92607812e+00,
         5.99593850e+00])
```

and of course we can find the corresponding y-values similarly:

```
In [96]: yy[x_mask]
Out[96]: 
array([ 0.        ,  2.02032307,  3.06460807,  4.25374305,  2.97366674,
        2.4770819 ,  2.79951527])
```

Above I've walked through the steps used to find the crossing points of the vertical grid lines; in the code the same was done for the horizontal grid lines.

Comment: More elegant than my answer :)

Comment: Excellent job! And nicely detailed. You made my day. Thank you unutbu.

Answer (score 4):

I hope the revision below helps... I have added the required comments.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Data
gps_track = np.array([[0,0],[1.2,2.3],[1.9,3],[3.2,4.3],[4,2.9],[6.5,3.1]])
x = gps_track[:,0]
y = gps_track[:,1]

# Define grid
binsize = 1
xmin, xmax = x.min(), x.max()
ymin, ymax = y.min(), y.max()
xi = np.arange(xmin, xmax+binsize, binsize)
yi = np.arange(ymin, ymax+binsize, binsize)

# Get mean values 
x_mean = np.mean(x)
y_mean = np.mean(y)

# Create the fit data for spline
x_fit_data = x/x_mean
y_fit_data = y/y_mean

# A spline of 3. degree
factor = 1000 # arbitrary sampling factor
g = np.arange(0, len(x))
fx = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(g, x_fit_data, k=3)
fy = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(g, y_fit_data, k=3)

# Get new data points
gg = np.linspace(0, len(x), len(x)*factor)
x_new = fx(gg) * x_mean
y_new = fy(gg) * y_mean

# Plot
fig = plt.figure()
plt.axis('equal') # optional. To set equal aspect ratio
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_xlim(xmin,xmax)
ax.set_ylim(ymin,ymax)
ax.plot(x_new, y_new)
ax.plot(x, y, 'ro') # if you also want to plot the sampling points
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

I think you should split your question into two: interpolation and plotting.